# reading from an input line with ""

Tags: c, string

I have this program that is supposed to read a line e.g `post "nice job" john` and i want to get every token in that line but for some reason i only get some of them.

Expected output:

```
post
nice job
john
```

My output:

```
post
nice
```

im sure im putting the correct format on sscanf so whats the problem i dont get why it doenst consider "nice job" as one word.

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char token1[128];
    char token2[128];
    char token3[128];
    char str[] = "post \"nice job\" john";
    sscanf(str,"%s \"%s\" %s",token1,token2,token3);
    puts(token1);
    puts(token2);
    puts(token3);
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: What if you tried `sscanf(str,"%s %s %s",token1,token2,token3);` ?

Comment: The second `%s` won't read `"nice job"` but stops at the first whitespace character, so it only reads `"nice"`. It would be easier using `%[]` format, or `fgets()` and `strtok()`.

Comment: Why is this tagged as C++? This is C code, except for the `new` (Which are leaked). In C++, this is easy, you can use `std::quoted`, `std::string` and a whole bunch of better approaches. I don't think this `sscanf` code should be salvaged.

Comment: i tried using `sscanf(str,"%s %s %s",token1,token2,token3);` but like i said i dont want the "" of nice job i only want the phrase

Comment: what i dont get is why is this at the 1st whitespace when i said in the format that the word had a ""

Comment: @MSalters 2 minutes ago it was "`char* token1 = new char[128];`" thus C++ - .Click the link (*`edited xxxx mins ago`*) and discover yourself why it was C++

Comment: You seem to have the expectation that  `\"%s\"` denotes `"` as a *delimiter*. It isn't. It's an input expectation, not a read-until delimiter., And since your failing to bother checking the result of your `scanf` call (failing to do do so should ALWAYS be considered a logical bug), you never know what worked and what didn't. I expect some cryptic format string like `"%s \"%[^\"\n]\" %s"` would probably do what you want, but I'm on board with MSalters.

Comment: @MartimCorreia not in the posted code, you didn't. You're looking at the strings, not the result of `sscanf` function. That `int` result code is there for a reason, and is unchecked in the posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `%s` reads `"nice"` because `%s` stops at the first whitespace. The format string then demands a match for a `"` quote, which isn't next (a space is next). The `scanf` functions don't skip input until a match is found, they stall. Always check the return value which should have been `3`.

This code

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main()
{
    char token1[128] = "";
    char token2[128] = "";
    char token3[128] = "";
    char str[] = "post \"nice job\" john";
    int res = sscanf(str, "%s \"%[^\"]\"%s", token1, token2, token3);
    printf("%d\n", res);
    puts(token1);
    puts(token2);
    puts(token3);
    return(0);
}
```

outputs

```
3
post
nice job
john
```